# How to get the image file URL in the ImageEdit control in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to get the image file URL in the ImageEdit control in WPF?I've tried this code, but it's not working:

```
string path = ((BitmapImage)imgEdit.Source).UriSource.AbsolutePath.ToString();


(imgEdit.Source as BitmapImage).UriSource ;
```

Comment: I think ImageEdit control doesn't have a direct property to get the image file URL. You can achieve this by accessing the source URI of the BitmapImage.

Comment: is this DevExpress?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used the DevExpress `ImageEdit` control but I used  their WPF library quite a bit back in the day and I still use their MVVM framework to this day. With that said I'm going to assume you are using MVVM but the important parts should be applicable regardless of how you're using WPF.

Without seeing how exactly you're using the `ImageEdit` it's hard to say but I'm going to guess that you actually need the user to be able to edit the image, because if not you should just use the standard `Image` control since the `ImageEdit` control doesn't always use the `Source` property ([docs](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.ImageEdit)). You can however use the `EditValue` to get (and set) the currently displayed image as a `byte[]`. It's been a while and I can't confirm this since I don't have a DevExpress license anymore, but I believe the `Source` property is just the `ImageSource` that's just used to load an image into memory and the `EditValue` is the actual image currently displayed. The `EditValue` is the what you actually care about on all of their edit controls.

So, if you need the actual file path you should bind the `Source` to an `ImageSource` in your ViewModel or you can bind to the path as a string `string` and use an `IValueConverter`.

```xml
<dxe:ImageEdit Source="{Binding ImagePath, Converter={converters:StringToImageSourceConverter}}" />
```

Here's a `StringToImageSourceConverter` that you can use to bind the `ImageEdit` `Source` to a `string` in a ViewModel.

```cs
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(ImageSource))]
public class StringToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is not string path) return null;
        if (!File.Exists(path)) return null;

        using var bmp = new Bitmap(path);
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        
        bmp.Save(ms, bmp.RawFormat);
        
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var img = new BitmapImage();
        img.BeginInit();
        
        img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        img.StreamSource = ms;
        
        img.EndInit();
        
        return img;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

That code highlights why you (likely) can't get the `UriSource` for the `ImageEdit` because it's just using the `Source` to load the `Bitmap` into memory as a `byte[]`.

Also, if you want to be able to use the converter directly without having to create a `StaticResource` you can add a `MarkupExtension` for it.

```cs
public class StringToImageSourceConverterExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public IValueConverter ItemConverter { get; set; }

    public StringToImageSourceConverterExtension() { }
    public StringToImageSourceConverterExtension(IValueConverter itemConverter) => ItemConverter = itemConverter;

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => new StringToImageSourceConverter();
}
```